# Question is to find two numbers within 1 to num that multiply to become num

Tags: python, time-limiting

```
t=int(input())
while t > 0:
    num=int(input())
    lst=[]
    n=0
    for i in range(1,math.floor(math.sqrt(num))+1):
        if num%i==0:
            lst.append(i)
    n=len(lst)
    if n == 1:
        print(1,num)
    else:
        print(lst[1],int(num/lst[1]))
    t-=1
```

Question is to find two numbers within `1 to num` that multiply to become `num`(for prime it is only 1, num and for rest any 2 factors). The time limit exceeded error is the thing that I am seeing now. Can anyone help me in optimizing it?

Comment: That's kind of a weird problem.  If you only need to return two numbers, can't you just return `1` and `num`?

Comment: noooooo for prime numbers 1 and num and for rest, other factors

Comment: Maybe only iterate up to `floor(sqrt(num))` since anything after that point is going to be a combination you've already tried?

Comment: tried it, but still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise the code by changing the limit inside the range to sqrt(num).I hope this solves your problem.

You can try like this:

```
 import math
 t= int(input())
 while(t>0):
     num = int(input())
     lst = []
     for i in range(1,(math.sqrt(num))+1):
          if(num%i == 0):
              lst.append((i,num/i))
              break
     print(lst[0])
     t= t-1
```

Comment: Can you tell me which part is wrong in this?

Comment: ```lst.append``` part, it is showing append() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given-this error

Comment: Yeah,I actually forgot to close one bracket.That is why this error is coming.Now I have fixed it.Can you try once again?

Answer (score 0):

- If you just need to find any 2 factors, there is no need to use a list. Just `break` after the first one found.
- As suggested in the comments, there is no need to iterate until `num`, as the factors will start to repeat. It is enough to iterate until the square.
- Lastly, you can take advantage of the built-in [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function to avoid calculating the modulus and then the division.

```py
from math import sqrt

num = int(input())
for n in range(2, int(sqrt(num)) + 1):
    div, mod = divmod(num, n)
    if mod == 0:
        print(n, div)
        break
else:
    print(1, num)
```

- This uses the [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct so in case no factors were found, just `1, num` will be printed which is always true.

Comment: try this code for ```num=45``` sir,you won't get any result

Comment: I don't know then, why it isn't showing in my case. Though all things are correct here

Comment: @ChandrachudPati make sure you are running correctly. There is no way to don't get any output here. As long as the loop didn't break, the `else` is executed. If the loop `break`s, then there is a print right before it...

Comment: Have a look sir, in my answer

Comment: Well, it is not equivalent to mine.... The `break` should be at the same level of the print... Please delete the answer as well

Comment: Sir, I have tried your code even, but it is showing time limit error, the exact one, break just after print and same identation

Comment: Well I really don't know how to optimize it further... I am not sure it is possible. You do have to go over all those numbers to check them in the end...